# How to display more data from the database (access) in VBA?

Tags: database, vba, select, recordset

What's the matter. After selecting a name from a ComboBox in ListBox have to display all the employees of the chosen company. And now my problem, always in a ListBox displays only 2 employees of the chosen company. The following piece of code responsible for displaying. For the record, I'm new in VBA. And of course, my question is why only two employees?

Procedure-click on the selected company from ComboBox:

```
Dim RecordSt As Recordset   
Dim db As Database
Dim query As String
Dim strKombi30 As String
Dim i As Integer

strKombi30 = Me.Kombi30.Value ''combobox

query = "SELECT [Employees].[First name], [Employees].[Name] FROM" & _
"[Employees] WHERE [Employees].[Company] = '" & Me.Kombi30

Set db = CurrentDb()

Set RecordSt = db.OpenRecordset(query)

RecordSt.MoveFirst

For i = 0 To RecordSt.RecordCount

    listContacts.AddItem (RecordSt.Fields("First name").Value & " " & RecordSt.Fields("Name").Value)

    RecordSt.MoveNext

Next i
```

Comment: Try changing the `For ..` line to `do while not RecordSt.EOF` and `Next` to `Loop` also are you missing a `& "'"` on the end of the sql (you should protect against injection here also)

Comment: I changed `for loop...` to the `do while...` as @Alex wrote, and now everything works as it should.

As for the lost `& "'"`, apparently I copied the code wrong without end of query, because in the original SQL query is good with `& "'"`. Thank's for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
strKombi30 = Me.Kombi30.Value ''combobox

query = "SELECT [Employees].[First name], [Employees].[Name] FROM" & _
"[Employees] WHERE [Employees].[Company] = '" &  strKombi30  & "'"
```

Comment: yes yes, I know, I just forgot to change `Me.Kombi30` to `strKombi30`, thanks